# How partial payment hit accounting statements in odoo 10 Using Point Of sale?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

As I have purchased pos_partial_payment module but found incomplete for my requirement so need to modify/add new functionality to it. As I perform partial payment (remaining credit amount) there is not changes to accounting.
For example, such partial paid amount is not showing in accounting and also not changing account receivable to Cash journal.

```py
 @api.one
def pay_partial_payment(self, amount):
    # Comment this method because we don't want generate payment accounting entry, if you want then just Uncomment it...
    print  "partnerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr id",self    
    print "****************codeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",amount
    #finding recivble 
    print  "id of account rec account",self.property_account_receivable_id.id
    lines = []              
    partner_line = {'account_id':self.property_account_receivable_id.id,
    'name':'/',
    'date':date.today(),
    'partner_id': self.id,
    'debit':float(amount),
    'credit':0.0,

    }
    lines.append(partner_line)              
    #find sale account
    recivable_ids = self.env['account.account'].search([('user_type_id.name','=','Receivable')])
    print "*********************************************************recivable_ids",recivable_ids
    rec_id = False
    if recivable_ids:
        rec_id  = recivable_ids[0]

    pos_line  = {'account_id':rec_id.id,
    'name':'pos partial payment',
    'date':date.today(),
    'partner_id': self.id,
    'credit':float(amount),
    'debit':0.0,
    }       
    lines.append(pos_line)
    line_list = [(0, 0, x) for x in lines]
    move_id = self.env['account.move'].create({'partner_id':self.id,
                                    'date':date.today(),
                                    # 'journal_id':7,
                                    'journal_id':6,
                                    'line_ids':line_list
                                    })

    return True
```